# To calculating the limit. I used L'Hôpital's rule, Failed.

Tags: limits

> $$
> f(x) = 8x^3 + 3x
> $$
>   Calculate
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1} (8x)  - f^{-1} (x) }{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}
> $$

I used L'Hôpital's rule, Failed. It seems hard to directly solve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ce9w.png)

Comment: See this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543743/72031

Answer (score 4):

You don't need that rule. As $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\sim(2x)^3$ so $f^{-1}(x)\sim\frac12x^{1/3}$, making your limit $\frac12\frac{\sqrt[3]{8}-1}{1}=\frac12$.

Comment: But it's not strict enough.

Comment: @WilliamLambert What do you mean by that? It seems [precise enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) to me.

Comment: from $$f(x) \sim (2x)^3 $$ to infer $$ f^{-1}(x) \sim \frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{3}} $$ isn't so convincing.

Comment: How to prove it more strictly, if you were taking a test. I cannot take it for granted.

Answer (score 0):

Given $y = 8x^3+3x$, the inverse function is $x=8y^3+3y$. Then, in the limit $\frac1x\rightarrow 0$,

$$\frac1x = \frac1{8y^3+3y}=\frac1{8y^3}+O(\frac1{y^5})$$

or,

$$y = f^{-1}(x)=\frac12x^{1/3}  + O(x^{-1/3})$$

Thus,

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1} (8x)  - f^{-1} (x) }{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}
=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac12(8x)^{1/3}  - \frac12x^{1/3} + O(x^{-1/3}) }{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}
=\frac12
$$